# Do time-constructible functions exist in relativized worlds?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, oracle-machines

I know that time-constructible functions are necessary to prove the Time Hierarchy Theorem and being computable functions they are computed by Turing Machines. I'm just confused in that since the Time Hierarchy Theorem relativizes I think this implies that TM's computing time-constructible functions exist in relativized worlds as well. But since testing string membership in the oracle language happens instantly, I don't see how they can be considered time-constructible. Is there another way to conceptualize it? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "relativized"?

Comment: @nirshahar I apologize for the confusion. I meant TMs with access to an oracle. The issue as I see it is that simulation can be carried out instantly through an oracle query so the notion of time-constructability may not have an interpretation when an oracle is accessible